# Burning large files on BD. Capacity confusion

Tags: command-line, udf, blu-ray

I have a couple of large files I want to burn to an M-Disc 50G BD-R DL. Files are larger than 4G so I have to use UDFv3, if I am not mistaken. (Or split, which I am not especially keen on doing.)

A graphical tool is not an option (no X on the server and those do a remarkably bad job on that anyway in my experience) so what I plan on doing is the following:

1. find the capacity of my medium with `dvd+rw-mediainfo`.
2. create a temporary file with `dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/bd.udf bs=2048 count=n` with n being an integer extracted from `mediainfo`'s output.
3. create a UDF filesystem on that temp with `mkudffs -b 2048 -l somelabel /tmp/bd.udf`
4. mount it with `mount -o loop -t udf /tmp/bd.udf ./mntpt`
5. populate it with my files `cp xyz* mntpt/`
6. unmount it `umount ./mntpt`
7. burn it with `growisofs -Z /dev/dvd=/tmp/bd.udf -speed=5`

Please correct me if this is not a good procedure. I'd be grateful for improvements.

What really confuses me is the output of `dvd+rw-mediainfo`:

```
INQUIRY:                [PIONEER ][BD-RW   BDR-UD03][1.11]
GET [CURRENT] CONFIGURATION:
 Mounted Media:         41h, BD-R SRM
 Media ID:              VERBAT/IMf
 Current Write Speed:   6.0x4495=26970KB/s
 Write Speed #0:        6.0x4495=26970KB/s
 Write Speed #1:        4.0x4495=17980KB/s
 Write Speed #2:        2.0x4495=8990KB/s
 Speed Descriptor#0:    00/24438783 R@6.0x4495=26970KB/s W@6.0x4495=26970KB/s
 Speed Descriptor#1:    00/24438783 R@4.0x4495=17980KB/s W@4.0x4495=17980KB/s
 Speed Descriptor#2:    00/24438783 R@2.0x4495=8990KB/s W@2.0x4495=8990KB/s
:-[ READ BD SPARE INFORMATION failed with SK=5h/MEDIUM NOT FORMATTED]: Wrong medium type
READ DISC INFORMATION:
 Disc status:           blank
 Number of Sessions:    1
 State of Last Session: empty
 "Next" Track:          1
 Number of Tracks:      1
READ FORMAT CAPACITIES:
 unformatted:       24438784*2048=50050629632
 00h(6000):     23652352*2048=48440016896
 32h(0):        23652352*2048=48440016896
 32h(0):        11200512*2048=22938648576
 32h(0):        24307712*2048=49782194176
READ TRACK INFORMATION[#1]:
 Track State:           invisible incremental
 Track Start Address:   0*2KB
 Next Writable Address: 0*2KB
 Free Blocks:           24438784*2KB
 Track Size:            24438784*2KB
READ CAPACITY:          0*2048=0
```

Should I use the "unformatted" block count for the temp file? What does "32h(0)" etc. mean? Is it necessary to somehow account for error correction spare blocks or something...? 
In a first test I used unformatted block count - 1 (don't ask me why;) ) and writing ends with an error message (that I unfortunately didn't record). The disc was readable though and md5 sums were fine.

Can someone point me to a definitve guide for writing BDs on the command line?

Comment: I would use the `truncate` command instead of `dd`. IMHO `growisofs` writes an additional error correction block of 256 MB, which you need to subtract from your payload size. (I did not find any information what the formatted sizes mean, unfortunately.)

Comment: Some more information can be found in https://mailing.comp.cdwrite.narkive.com/v2PLtJHY/blu-ray-disk-capacities-really and https://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/users/2013-July/439049.html so you may assume the usable size for `growisofs` is 23652352*2048=48440016896. For safety I would subtract 256MB as mentioned above.